# URL Redirecin Vhost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, vhosts

How can i redirect `something.some.*` to `something.some` in vhos

I tried various rewrite rules but none worked so no use pasting them..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to redirect a hostname?  I'm not entirely sure as to what you are trying to do.

If my assumption is correct then something like this should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^something\.some\..*$
RewriteRule (.*) http://something.some/$1 [R=301,L]
```